# Spring Boot validation of RequestBody Dto annotated in Rest API

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my controller I have annotated the request parameter with the `@Valid` annotation and the field of my DTO with the `@NotNull` annotation, but the validation doesn't seem to work.

Are there any configurations to do in order to proceed with the validation? Following there are the Controller and the DTO class details.

```java
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/download_pdf")
public class PurchaseController {

    @Autowired
    private IPurchaseService iPurchaseService;

    @Loggable
    @RequestMapping(value = "view_order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity getPDF(@RequestBody @Valid CustomerOfferDto offer,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) {
        return iPurchaseService.purchase(offer, response);
    }
}

public class CustomerOfferDto {
    @NotNull
    private String agentCode;

    // getter and setter...

 }
```

Comment: Try @Validated instead and confirm that you have a JSR-303 implementation (Hibernate Validator) in your classpath.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried also with the @NotEmpty annotation on the field.

Comment: Can you share your dependencies list?

Comment: I added these dependencies
`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
 <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
 <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 2):

Following are the steps I did to make it work.

**Add dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Constraints in DTO class:**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ValidTaskDTO
public class TaskDTO {

    @FutureOrPresent
    @NotNull(message = "DueDate must not be null")
    private ZonedDateTime dueDate;

    @NotBlank(message = "Title cannot be null or blank")
    private String title;

    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private RecurrenceType recurrenceType;

    @Future
    @NotNull(message = "RepeatUntil date must not be null")
    private ZonedDateTime repeatUntil;

}
```

**RestController method with `@Valid` annotation on requestBody argument**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
@Validated
public class TaskController {

    @PostMapping
    public TaskDTO createTask(@Valid @RequestBody TaskDTO taskDTO) {
      .....
    }

}
```

On making a `POST` request with requestbody containing `null` value for `dueDate`, I got the expected error message as shown below.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-01-20T11:38:53.043232",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "DueDate must not be null"
}
```

I hope this helps. For details on class level constraints, hav a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pkaYjJVlyk&t=4s).

Answer (score 1):

In my projects, this usually happens when I change my code from lets say `Entity` to `DTO` and forget to add `@ModelAttribute` to my `DTO` parameter.

If this also happened to you, try adding `@ModelAttribute("offer")` to your `DTO` parameter.